# Displaying query result in jsp : table field issue

Tags: java, sql, database

the result of my query is displaying the same value for a field present in 3 tables. 
here is my query :

```
String sql =select m.libelle,
       tm.libelle,
       eq.libelle,
       h.zone,session.getTransaction().commit();
       h.etat,
       t.fx,
       t.uid 
  from WEBCARE.TYPE_EQUIPEMENT te,
       WEBCARE.MARQUE m,
       WEBCARE.TYPE_MARQUE tm,
       WEBCARE.ETAT_EQUIPEMENT eq,
       BSG7.HORAIRE h,
       WEBCARE.EQUIPEMENT e,
       WEBCARE.INSTALL_EQUIPEMENT i,
       WEBCARE.TRANSMETTEUR t 
 where i.id_equipement= e.id and 
       h.id_ref       = e.id and 
       eq.id          = e.id_etat and 
       tm.id_marque   = m.id and 
       e.id_marque    = m.id and 
       eq.id_type     = e.id_type and 
       t.id           = e.id and 
       tm.id_type_equipement = e.id_type and 
       te.id          = e.id_type and 
       te.id          = 1
 SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
 query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
 List equipement=query.list();
```

the m.libelle is repeated for the columns having the same name of this field even if its in different tables .the query displays the correct results on mysql console,the problem is when displaying in java console or jsp.
any help to solve this problem?

Comment: tm.libelle, as lib1, em.libelle as lib2

Comment: @Jacek Cz  tried it didn't work..

Comment: This solved the problem : select m.libelle,concat(TYPE_MARQUE.libelle,'') as gamme,concat(ETAT_EQUIPEMENT.libelle,'') as etat_equipement....